# Fix JIT after install and uninstall of Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, jit

After installing Xdebug JIT is no longer working:

> PHP Warning:  JIT is incompatible with third party extensions that override zend_execute_ex(). JIT disabled. in Unknown on line 0

Have uninstalled Xdebug and reinstalled PHP, but I still get the error. How to fix it?

```
apt-get remove --purge php-xdebug

apt-get install --reinstall php8.0-fpm php8.0-apcu php8.0-imap php8.0-curl php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring php8.0-bcmath php8.0-xml php8.0-redis php8.0-intl php8.0-soap php8.0-ssh2
```

Comment: Although this works, all you really need to do is to disable the `xdebug` extension in the php.ini file.  Just prepend a ";" on this line: `zend_extension=xdebug.so`

Answer (score 6):

If you still get the error, then Xdebug (or another extension) is still being loaded. `php -m` will tell you which modules are loaded, and `php --ini` which INI files PHP is using, which might load xdebug (or another extension).

Comment: thats strange `php -m` lists `xdebug` even that I already `apt-get remove --purge php-xdebug`

Comment: I found the ini file and now it works :)

Comment: Strangely this wasn't an issue in PHP 8.0.0  It started to appear in PHP 8.0.1 and above.  I just ran into this using PHP 8.0.3.  I disabled the Xdebug extension and JIT works. The bug is documented here: [https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80608](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80608)

Comment: @dougB In PHP 8.0.0 it would just crash PHP instead ;-)

Comment: Still an issue for xdebug (3.3.1) and PHP 8.2 in 2024.